# почему action "save_post" вызывается 3 раза?

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action('save_post', 'new_post_created');

function new_post_created($post_id) {

$post_log = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/new_post.txt';
$title = get_the_title($post_id);

if (file_exists($post_log)) {
    $file = fopen($post_log, 'a');
} else {
    $file = fopen($post_log, 'w');
}

$message = "post $title was created \n";

fwrite($file, $message);
}
```

Но при созданий поста в файл new_post.txt добавляется title 3 раза

Answer (score 0):

У вас висит несколько хуков на действии 'save_post'. Пишите в файл

```
$message = print_r( debug_backtrace(), true );
```

И вы увидите там стек вызовов.

Ну а лучше освоить xdebug.